# Batch is not displaying empty value

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I am currently working on a batch script that would move files from a source to a destination based on a master file. I wanted to add a condition that if there is a missing value from the columns then it would skip that line. I tried all the solutions that I found but it won't trigger the if condition. Here's a snippet of the code:

```
for /f "usebackq tokens=1-3 skip=1 delims=," %%a in (%MasterFilePath%) do (
set dest=%%c
set src=%%b 
if !dest!=="" do (echo destination for source !src! is empty)
```

Here's a sample of the master file:

```
FolderName,SrcPath,DestPath
FolderA,C:\Work\FolderA,
FolderB,C:\Work\FolderB,C:\Work\Sample\Dest2
FolderC,C:\Work\FolderC,C:\Work\Sample\Dest3
```

Comment: Why bother assigning the for variable to an environmental variable.  Just use the `FOR` variable in the comparison.  Regardless you have two problems with the `IF` command. 1) There is no `DO` with the `IF` command. 2) String comparisons are literal. If quotes are on one side of the comparison then they must be on the other side of the comparison for the comparison to be TRUE. Lastly, I am going to assume you have delayed expansion enabled at the top of your script.

Comment: And just so you are aware, if the SourcePath is empty and the destination is not, the destination path will get assigned to `%%b` when the `FOR` command iterates that line of the input file.

Comment: quotes are included in the value being compared `if !dest!==""` will never execute successfully. If you insit upon assigning to a variable, Use instead `if "!dest!"==""` or even `If not defined dest`

Comment: I have some questions regarding your submission. First of all, is it possible that any of your directory names could contain a comma, _(because those are perfectly valid characters in a directory object)_. If so, how is the master file created? If it is a properly created CSV output, the fields should be double-quoted in such cases, are there any? I would also have to ask whether it is possible that there are more than three fields in each record? I ask because if there are, and there is an empty field, i.e. `string1,string2,,string4`, then a `for` loop would see `string4` as the third token.

Comment: @Squashman Thank you a lot for your input, I have already removed the assigning of variables and yes, delayed expansion is enabled within the code. I did not know that `for` command would iterate the missing value, what could be the workaround for a loop?

Comment: @Compo commas are not part of the directory as of the moment and data are not inside double quotes , and yes, there could be more than three records in the master file. What's an alternative for looping a routine other than a `for` command?

Comment: @Joshua, Compo is asking if there will be more than three **fields**.  Not three **records**.

Comment: You would be well advised to use a tool that understands CSV files. If you are on a supported Windows system, PowerShell will already be installed. You could also use Python, Perl, and many other languages if you have them.

Answer (score 0):

The `FOR /F` command will always treat consecutive delimiters as one delimiter.  So if you delimited file has an empty field and it does not have quotes, the fields will shift to the left on you.  So to work around this you can two `FOR /F` commands.  The first one will read in the whole line.  That variable is then forced to put quotes around every field using string substitution. You can then use the second `FOR /f` command to split the fields up into the amount of fields you need.

```
@ECHO OFF
set "MasterFilePath=file.txt"
FOR /F "usebackq skip=1 delims=" %%G IN ("file.txt") DO (
    set "line=%%G"
    setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
    SET "line="!line:,=","!""
    for /f "tokens=1-3 delims=," %%A IN ('echo !line!') do (
        IF NOT "%%~B"=="" IF NOT "%%~C"=="" ECHO ROBOCOPY "%%~B" "%%~C"
    )
    endlocal
)
```

For the sake of brevity I am just checking if both the source and destination is not empty and then echoing the robcopy command to the screen.

With your input example you would see this.

```
ROBOCOPY "C:\Work\FolderB" "C:\Work\Sample\Dest2"
ROBOCOPY "C:\Work\FolderC" "C:\Work\Sample\Dest3"
```